# ManyToManyField, filtering by matching all related values

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have in my model to classes:

```
User: name
Pair: users=ManyToManyField(User)
```

I want to make working and in the next step optimal query which allows me to get all pairs of two users.
This code of course not works, but shows my problem.
The order of user_1 and user_2 is not important.

```
def get_pair_by_users(user_name_1, user_name_2):
    return Pairs.objects.filter(users__name=user_name_1 & users__name=user_name_2)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? probably a sample data of User and Pair and what are you trying to accomplish as result?

Comment: I have table Pairs, where I saved each "meeting" of users. I want to get all Pairs records filtered by joined users: https://pastebin.com/jzTkKnxR

Comment: example: https://pastebin.com/EHTdeQXS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
def get_pair_by_users(user_name_1, user_name_2):
    return Pairs.objects.filter(
        users__name=user_name_1
    ).filter(
        users__name=user_name_2
    )
```

It is important to work with *two* [**`.filter(…)`** calls [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter), since then we make *two* JOINs. Otherwise we will query for an item that has a user that has as name both `user_name_1` and `user_name_2`, which of course does not make much sense.